# How to specify MinGW64 for codeblocks 17.02 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, path, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I have downloaded CodeBlocks 17.02 without mingw and installed it, then I downloaded MinGW64 from here(https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) and only changed the architecture option from  i686 to x86_64 during the installation and left the rest as default. Then tried to add this path to system paths: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin. But when I opened the CodeBlocks, it couldn't find the compiler. Also when I go to settings>compiler and try to set GNU GCC compiler it says: can not find the compiler!

How should I specify the MinGW64 for CodeBlocks om Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the MinGW 8.1.0 in CodeBlocks.
The steps are: Settings -> Compiler -> GNU GCC Compiler -> Toolchain executables -> path\to\mingw64 (without bin). Then confirm.

[image]

Comment: I set up the toolchain then get undefined reference to __gxxpersonality

Comment: This is another question. You should search on Google by entering "undefined reference to __gxxpersonality"