# how to specify the C standard type if my compiler is Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, c99

I am using Cygwin for my compiler while coding in Codeblocks IDE. Here is what I did in Cygwin 64:

```
$ gcc -std=c99
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

However, it's not working. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Cygwin_Compiler

Comment: this was already done , so it's not the problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile a c program in its simplest form to a certain standard, you can use the following command:

```
gcc -std=c99 -W -Wall main.c -o main
```

Comment: thanks! but since I'm using the Codeblocks IDE with the compiler set as Cygwin, how should I specify the standard such that I can just click "run&build" in Codeblocks IDE?

Comment: Related: [How to specify MinGW64 for codeblocks 17.02 on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51349548/15032688)

Comment: Related: [Code::Blocks - MinGW Installation](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/MinGW_installation)

Comment: To set compiler flag on Code::Blocks IDE: [How to add compiler flags on codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33209049/15032688)